# Docker installation problem (ubuntu 20.04 LTS) - E: The repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \ Release' does not have a Release file

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, apt-get

I have a problem installing docker on my virtual machine.
I have followed the steps below:

**1. Older versions of Docker were called docker, docker.io, or docker-engine. If these are installed, uninstall
them:**

`sudo apt-get remove docker docker-engine docker.io containerd runc`

**2. Update the apt package index**

`sudo apt-get update`

**3. install packages to allow apt to use a repository over HTTPS:**

```
   sudo apt-get install \
   apt-transport-https \
   ca-certificates \
   curl \
   gnupg \
   lsb-release
```

**4. Add Docker’s official GPG key:**

`curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg`

**5. Use the following command to set up the stable repository:**

```
   echo \
     "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg]
   https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
      $(lsb_release -cs) stable" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list >
   /dev/null
```

**6. Update the apt package index**

`sudo apt-get update`

At this point - after typing sudo apt-get update - I get the following error

```
root@xxx:/home/xxx# sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://us-central1.gce.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://us-central1.gce.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease                                    
Hit:3 http://us-central1.gce.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease                                  
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease                                                  
Ign:5 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \ InRelease                                              
Err:6 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \ Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 13.249.137.69 443]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \ Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Content of `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list`

`deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg] download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \ focal stable`

is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Content of your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list`?

Comment: deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu  \  focal stable

Comment: Well, this is your problem then

Comment: Should I change ``focal stable`` to: ``deb [arch = amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu eoan stable``  does it make sense?

Comment: Hold on, you've edited your last comment, this is not what I was answering to.

Comment: anyway, mine says `deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu   focal stable`

Comment: Yes, sorry. I didn't notice that it was enough to correct the syntax error. Thank you, that's work.

Comment: No worries, since it worked, I've posted this as the answer, in case it helps someone else in the future

Comment: FWIW I had the same issue. I was on debian 11 bullseye which is not listed on the docker repository. I followed this installation guide instead of the one on docker site linuxiac.com/how-to-install-docker-on-debian-11-bullseye

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Make sure the content of the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list` corresponds  to the output of the command in the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/#set-up-the-repository), bullet #3.

At the time of this writing executing the command on my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS results in the following content of the docker.list file:

`deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu   focal stable`

which seems to be different from that of yours.

Comment: This worked for me. As I am using Mint 20.1 I had `ulyssa stable`, and changing to `focal stable` fixed the issue.  You are perhaps being downvoted as this is noted in bullet 3 of the docs, but I missed it there and found it here, so thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The #3 point from the link helped me out

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem,

my docker.list file was

```
deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu      jammy stable
```

Too many spaces between `/ubuntu` and `jammy stable`... once taking out additional spaces `sudo apt-get update` worked.

Comment: FWIW I had the same issue but in my case spaces did not help it. I was on debian 11 bullseye which is not listed on the docker repository.

I followed this installation guide instead of the one on docker site
https://linuxiac.com/how-to-install-docker-on-debian-11-bullseye/