# Docker repository does not have a release file for apt-get update on jammy release

Tags: docker, playwright, ubuntu-22.04

Trying to apt update and I am getting this, due to this I cannot install playwright as it fails when I do so
I get this every time i do so

```
Err:13 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian jammy Release                  
  404  Not Found [IP: 108.158.245.93 443]

...none
Reading package lists... Done                                    
E: The repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/debian jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I tried changing the docker.list value but no change here. also can anybody point me to where I can change or remove

```
Err:13 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian jammy Release                  
  404  Not Found [IP: 108.158.245.93 443]
```

Comment: Did you see [Docker installation problem (ubuntu 20.04 LTS) - E: The repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \ Release' does not have a Release file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68712058/docker-installation-problem-ubuntu-20-04-lts-e-the-repository-https-down)?

Comment: I saw this but I my docker.list value is correct, not sure why it still gives me this error, ```none
Err:13 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian jammy Release                  
  404  Not Found [IP: 108.158.245.93 443]
```
but I can't see this anywhere not even in the docker.lists

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I have resolved this by removing - `none archive_uri-https_download_docker_com_linux_debian-jammy.list`
and `none archive_uri-http_cz_archive_ubuntu_com_ubuntu-jammy.list`